# Split quantity to have unit price with two decimals

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a way to divide the quantity in such a way that the unit price to be with two decimal places:

For example I have a product with:

```
initial_quantity = 2880
initial_value = 488,95

# the price per piece:
initial_unit_price = initial_value / initial_quantity = 0,1697743055555556  # not good
```

But I want to split the product in how many small quantities are needed to have unit prices with two decimals. For example how I divided manually:

```
quantity = 2800
unit_price = 0,16
value = 448.00 (quantity * unit_price)

quantity = 79
unit_price = 0,51
value = 40,29

quantity = 1
unit_price = 0,66
value = 0,66

TOTAL 488,95
```

What I tried:

```py
def split_quantity(quantity, total_value):
  quantities = []

  # Find piece price
  initial_unit_price = total_value / quantity  # 0,1697743055555556
  
  # Check if unit price has more than two decimals
  if len(str(initial_unit_price).split(".")[1] > 2: # True
    
    # I tried to adjust the unit price
    unit_price = round(initial_unit_price) # 0,17

    # But the rest I don't know how to find the correct method to split
  
  else:
    quantities.append({
       "quantity": quantity,
       "unit_price": initial_unit_price,
       "value": total_value
    })
  return quantities

result = split_quantity(2880, 488,95);
result2 = split_quantity(3, 537,46)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you need to split? You are already rounding the unit price to 2 decimals. Perhaps clarify your question.

Comment: Do you want to find the largest matching quantity? You could simply try them all in descending order (initial/2, initial/3, etc.).

Comment: If I rounding 0.17 x 2880 = 489,5 which is bigger than initial_value (488,95)

Comment: Please keep in mind that the Python code **must** use `.` as a decimal point, **not** `,`. If you are in a place where `,` is used as a decimal point, you can configure Python to *print* floating-point numbers that way, but the source code must still use `.`.

Comment: (Aside from answering what should be obviously a duplicate, both answers you were given here are simply wrong. `round` is not a robust solution to the problem. Fundamentally you only want to *display* the numeric values a certain way, or rather, *convert them to string following specific formatting rules*. That should be handled with the string formatting tools. Please see the linked duplicate.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel what you suggest me is not what I looking for. Read again the question

Comment: Sorry, I read it again a few times and I can't find any other meaning in it. If you mean something else then please try to explain it more clearly.

Comment: Maybe it is beyond your capacity to understand. Look at the example I gave. Do you see something about removing decimals? 

Answer (score -1):

Why are you not using `round()` here? You're using it inside your function already. The second argument to the `round()` function is *ndigits*, or the number of digits you want to round to (in your case, 2).

Your code could look something like this:

```py
def split_quantity(quantity, total_value):
  quantities = []

  # Find piece price, round to 2 decimal places
  price = round(total_value / quantity, 2)  # 0,17
  
  quantities.append({
    "quantity": quantity,
    "unit_price": price,
    "value": total_value
  })
  return quantities
```

If you cannot exceed the value, you could do something with `math.ceil()`, or you could do a check after rounding:

```py
def split_quantity(quant, total):
    price = round(total/quant, 2)
    
    if price * quantity > total_value:
        price -= 0.01
        price = round(price, 2) # because of floating point errors
    
    return {
      'quantity': quant,
      'unit_price': price,
      'value': value
    }
```

Another thing you could do is multiply everything by 100 and work in integers, throwing out any further decimals:

```py
def split_quantity(quant, value):
    price = (value/quant  # get the real price
             * 100  # move the decimal place right by two
             // 1   # drop the decimal
             / 100) # move the decimal back to the original loc
    return {...}
```

Comment: Because I will exceed the total value of the invoice if I round   2880 pieces * 0.17 price per piece = 489,5, which is bigger than total value (488,95)

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use fractions of a [cent, penny, franc, euro]?

Comment: added a couple of code examples

Answer (score -1):

assuming the commas are a regional/locale designation, what you want is a "round down" rather than `round` operation.

```py
def round_down(qty, val):
    return int(val / qty * 100) / 100

for desired_value, qty, initial_value in ((0.16, 2880, 488.95), (0.51, 79, 40.29), (0.66, 1, 0.66)):
    # assert round_down(qty, initial_value) == desired_value
    print(f'{round_down(qty, initial_value)= }, desired value: {desired_value}')
```

output:

```
round_down(qty, initial_value)= 0.16, desired value: 0.16
round_down(qty, initial_value)= 0.51, desired value: 0.51
round_down(qty, initial_value)= 0.66, desired value: 0.66
```

now with your code, is there a reason you are returning a list when you only pass it a single pair of arguments?
I would consider coding something like this:

```py
from pprint import pp


def round_down(qty, val):
    return int(val / qty * 100) / 100


def split_quantity(qty, val):
    split_val = round_down(qty, val)
    value = qty * split_val
    return dict(quantity=qty, unit_price=split_val, value=value)


quantities = []
quantities.append(split_quantity(2880, 488.95))
quantities.append(split_quantity(3, 537.46))
pp(quantities)
print("TOTAL:", sum(i['value'] for i in quantities))
```

output:

```
[{'quantity': 2880, 'unit_price': 0.16, 'value': 460.8},
 {'quantity': 3, 'unit_price': 179.15, 'value': 537.45}]
TOTAL: 998.25
```

Comment: but the output exceed the initial quantity (2880) and the total value (488,95)